# Eager loading via user defined function in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading, user-defined-functions

I’m using Entity framework 4.1. Fluent API to map my model to pre-defined database. Is there any way to use eager initialization of complex properties via stored procedures or user defined functions?
For example:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Model Model {get;set}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

Let’s say I have a user defined function in the database that takes Car Id as an input and returns list of parts. Is there any chance to make EF using it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [How to: Call a User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd490951%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)